# Move buttons below text

Tags: css

I am trying to figure this out. My goal is to have the two `buttons`... the `yes` and `no` buttons to show **below** the text. I can change the html ofcourse, but I want/need to do it with **CSS only**. Possible?

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 
.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 
.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<button class="yes"><span>yes</span></button>
<button class="no"><span>no</span></button>
Here you can vote
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of using `position: absolute;` on anything unless it is absolutely necessary or you know exactly what you're doing. Instead you can wrap your buttons in another container and then make your `.box` a flex-container with direction `column`. like this:

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
 
.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 
.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="yes"><span>yes</span></button>
    <button class="no"><span>no</span></button>
  </div>
  
  Here you can vote
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yz4gfdv/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your buttons inside a `<div>`

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Here you can vote
  <div>
  <button class="yes"><span>yes</span></button>
  <button class="no"><span>no</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS Way which you are expecting

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <button class="yes"><span>yes</span></button>
  <button class="no"><span>no</span></button> Here you can vote
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without editing your HTML at all you can indeed use CSS to move the buttons below (although editing your HTML would be easiest). Something like this would work:

```
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50px;
 }

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing, you can use float: right attribute to float 2 buttons "Yes" and "No" to the right.

The second thing, you can use margin-top to move down 2 buttons "Yes" and "No" to the bottom of the text.

The Third thing, you can use left position to set the width of these two buttons with the left side.

The final thing, you can use the position absolute attribute to fix the position of these two buttons.

Hope it help, regard!

```css
.box {
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 
.yes {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
 }
 
.no {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 52px;
  left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<button class="yes"><span>yes</span></button>
<button class="no"><span>no</span></button>
Here you can vote
</div>
```